# How to show headers in R ggplot loop with 2 types of visuals

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I want to print graphs for all the columns in my dataset in a loop, so that each graph will have the appropreate column name.

I managed to do so with the following code:

```
headers <- names(dataset)
for (name in headers) {
 print(ggplot(dataset, aes_string(x= name)) + geom_bar())
}
```

Now I got stuck in the following addition: my data is either continues (int) or categorical (string), thus I added an if condition (if in - plot a density line and if factor - plot a bar chart.

It also worked, but now each graph's name is literally 'x' rather than the column name.

```
for (colum in dataset) {
 if (class(colum) == "integer") {
   print(ggplot(dataset, aes_string(x= column)) + geom_density())
 } else {
   print(ggplot(dataset, aes_string(x= column)) + geom_bar())
 }
}
```

Adding the header list gets the proper names, but turns all my graphs into bar charts, for x gets a string every single time and evokes the second if statement.

How can I keep the if statement working, but add the proper names of the columns in the graphs' aesthetics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
library(ggplot2)

for (column in names(dataset)) {
  if (is.integer(dataset[[column]])) {
    print(ggplot(dataset, aes(x= .data[[column]])) + geom_density())
  } else {
    print(ggplot(dataset, aes(x= .data[[column]])) + geom_bar())
  }
}
```

Note that `aes_string` has been deprecated and it is recommended to use `.data` which will preserve the column names on x-axis.